# Map fetched data in React with Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend, fetch-api

i´m trying to fetch all the product i have in my DB (mongodb) using the fetch API. The result i get i store in a slice using Redux Toolkit. The problem is  when i pass the data fetched and stored to a component as a props, the result is not beeing displayed.

**slice**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  products: [],
};

const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "product",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setProducts(state, action) {
      state.products.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
});

export const { setProducts } = productSlice.actions;

export default productSlice.reducer;
```

**store**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import uiSlice from "./ui-slice";
import userSlice from "./user-slice";
import productSlice from './product-slice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    ui: uiSlice,
    user: userSlice,
    products: productSlice
  },
});

export default store;
```

**function i used to fetch the products**

```
export const fetchProduct = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:xx/xxx");
      const data = await response.json();
      let loadedProducts = [];
      for (const key in data) {
        loadedProducts.push({
          id: data[key]._id,
          productName: data[key].productName,
          price: data[key].price,
          imageUrl: data[key].imageUrl,
        });
      }
      dispatch(setProducts(loadedProducts));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

**I get the value stored in my redux state with useSelector and use it to fetch the products**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { fetchProduct } from "../../actions/productActions";

import Hero from "../hero/Hero";
import Footer from "../footer/Footer";
import DisplayProductsList from "../displayProduct/DisplayProductsList";

export default function Home() {
  const productsInfo = useSelector((state) => state.products.products);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProduct());
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <>
      <Hero />
      <DisplayProductsList products={productsInfo} />
      <Container fluid>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

**And then i map it**

```
export default function DisplayProductsList(props) {
  console.log(props) 
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.products.map((product) => (
        <DisplayProducts
        key={product.id}
        imageUrl={product.imageUrl}
        name={product.productName}
        price={product.price}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

**console log the props i sent**
[image]

**if i console log the state in the selector this is what i get**
[image]

**code in the backend**

```
module.exports.fetchProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const products = await Product.find({});
    console.log(products)
    if (products) {
      res.json(products);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

[image]

Comment: Print the whole `state` in the selector to check what it is

Comment: Can you share your code in `codesandbox` ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/CDInacio/Sistemas-Web-1-Trab-Pratico?file=/frontend/src/App.js:301-333

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code, you are storing an array of objects i.e. 'loadedProducts' into 'products' which is also an array. Something like this:
[nested array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxJhw.png)

So in order to get the productsInfo in DisplayProductsList component, instead of doing this:

```
{props.products.map((product) => (
        <DisplayProducts
        key={product.id}
        imageUrl={product.imageUrl}
        name={product.productName}
        price={product.price}
        />
))}
```

you should do something like this:

```
 {props.products[0].map((product) => (
   //rest of your code
      ))}
```

Comment: didn´t work, i get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are getting the response from DB correctly? If yes, please share the snippet of the response you get, also the file where you have created the store?

Comment: done, please check it

Comment: I have a doubt, is that first output for console.log(state) or console.log(state.products.products)? Because I think the problem is most probably in the line where you are trying to select products from the store.

Comment: console.log(state.products.products)

Comment: try passing any other prop to the DisplayProductsList component. If you get this value now, so one another possible reason would be that your component DisplayProductsList loads first while you get the products later.

Comment: i uploaded a image of the printed props i pass to the component DisplayProductsList. I´m not getting undefined anymore, but the result is still not beeing displayed.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/CDInacio/Sistemas-Web-1-Trab-Pratico?file=/frontend/src/App.js:301-333

Comment: ok..did you use products[0].map(....) and not products.map(...) and still not getting the output?

Comment: Its kind of strange what is happening. When i change  products.map(....) to products[0].map(....)  the products are displayed. But if i refresh the page i get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: I think the simple reason is that your when you refresh the page your Home component re-renders and a new action is dispatched to fetchProduct() but the child component DisplayProductsList is rendered before that. So you can use useEffect() with a dependency products in the DisplayProductsList component to force it to re-render whenever the products change. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, but i don´t know if this is the best pratice

Answer (score 0):

While getting the state value (productsinfo) from redux use this - state.product.products

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. If possible, please [edit](/posts/78162905/edit) your post to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information in [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) - *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*  I suggest reading some highly voted answers for examples.  Thanks!